# output file descriptor redirection

Tags: ksh, file-descriptor

I need to be able to redirect output to a file and also check the return code of a script in KSH (can't use pipestatus or pipefail), I have found a solution but I'm not sure what the significance of file discriptor 4 is, can someone explain please?

```
{
rc=$(
{
  {
    . somescript.sh 2>&1
    echo "$?" >&3
  } | tee -a somefile.txt
} 3>&1 >&4 4>&-
)
} 4>&1

echo "${rc}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rc=$(...)` means that the return code will be whatever is printed on file descriptor (fd) `1` by the code within the `(...)`.  So, somehow, what `somescript.sh` outputs has to be moved off fd `1` and then brought back later.  The `echo` line outputs `somescript.sh`'s return code to fd `3`.  Then, `3>&1` sends the saved return code to fd `1`, where `$(...)` expects it.  However, this means the old fd `1` (from `{somescript 2>&1 } | tee`) doesn't have anywhere to go.  So the old fd `1` is redirected to fd `4` with `>&4` (and the input side is closed with `4>&-` since it won't be used).  Then, once the `$(...)` is over, the `4>&1` at the end puts the output of the `somescript|tee` back onto fd `1` where other programs expect it to be.

Whew!

Without the `>&4`, the output of `somescript.sh` and the output of `echo "$?"` would be mixed on fd `1` because of the `3>&1`.  So fd `4` is a holding pen for the actual output of `somescript.sh` during the time that fd `1` is being used to carry the return code.

Comment: I always thought that $(...) reads from stdout, which is what fd 1 usually points too, but if it reads from fd 1 then that would make a lot of sense.  Thanks.

Comment: fd 1 does not "point to" standard output; it *is* standard output.

Comment: @chepner ah ok, thanks for the clarification, and normally stdout points to the terminal then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a named pipe, you can dispense with all the file-descriptor wrangling:

```
mkfifo p
tee -a somefile.txt < p &
. somescript.sh > p
rc=$?
```

Here, we run `tee` in the background, letting it read its input from a named pipe `p`. Once that job is started, we source the script and redirect its output to the named pipe. Once the script completes, you can save its exit status to `rc` using an ordinary assignment statement. This will also close the shells end of the pipe, which will cause the other end to close as well and allow `tee` to exit.

Comment: If you ran this with fd `1` initially pointing to the terminal, would `tee ... &` cause `tee` to stop with a `SIGTTOU` when `somescript.sh` started producing output on `p`?

Comment: In theory, yes, but `ksh` should be overriding the default action on `SIGTTOU` to allow `tee` to write to the terminal directly. (To be honest, I had to look up what `SIGTTOU` was because I hadn't noticed any problem when I tested this.)

Comment: ["Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~peter/knuthnote.pdf) *Knuth* :)    Thanks!